# Finitely generated projective resolution of a module over a regular local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a regular local ring and let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then there exists a finite projective resolution $P_\bullet\to M\to 0$. However, need there exist a finite projective resolution consisting of finitely generated projective modules? What if we require that $M$ be finitely generated?

Comment: Of course if $M$ is not finitely generated, then there is no surjection $P_0\to M$ from a finitely generated projective $P_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular local ring $R$ is Noetherian by hypothesis. If $M$ is a finitely
generated $R$-module, then there is a finite rank free module $F$ and a surjection $F\to M$
fitting into a short exact sequence
$$0\to N\to F\to M\to0.$$
As $N$ is a submodule of the finitely generated free module $F$ over the
Noetherian ring $R$ then $N$ is finitely generated. Iterating this, gives a resolution of $N$ by finitely generated free modules. As $R$ is regular,
it has finite global dimension, and the iterated kernels are eventually projective (so free) and the resolution can be brought to an end.

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite see while $R$ having finite global dimension implies that this process should eventually end. The global dimension is the supremum over $R$-modules of the infimum of the lengths of resolutions. Why does that imply that this particular resolution should be finite?

Comment: In the exact sequence above, if $M$ is not projective, the projective dimension of $N$ is strictly less than that of $M$, so iterating one eventually gets a kernel of projective dimension zero, that is a projective module (indeed free as projectives over local rings are free). @Anonymous

Comment: Interesting. Is it a well known fact that the projective dimension should decrease like that?

Comment: Pretty much all texts on homological algebra cover this ...